# Bootstrap 4 Flexbox disable flex for specific item

Tags: flexbox, bootstrap-4

I am aligning my items with `d-flex`. Using [Bootstrap 4 Flexbox](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox/#enable-flex-behaviors) (see image).

[image]

This is my markup:

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-block">
    <div class="bulk-filter-wrapper d-flex">

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="edit-status">Published status</label>
        <select data-drupal-selector="edit-status" id="edit-status" name="status" class="form-select form-control"><option value="All" selected="selected">- Any -</option><option value="1">Published</option><option value="2">Unpublished</option></select>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="edit-type">Content type</label>
        <select data-drupal-selector="edit-type" id="edit-type" name="type" class="form-select form-control"><option value="All" selected="selected">- Any -</option><option value="organization">Organisatie</option><option value="page">Page</option><option value="person">Persoon</option></select>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="edit-title">Title</label>
        <input data-drupal-selector="edit-title" type="text" id="edit-title" name="title" value="" size="30" maxlength="128" class="form-text form-control">
      </div>

      <input data-drupal-selector="edit-submit-content" type="submit" id="edit-submit-content" value="Filter" class="button js-form-submit form-submit btn btn-primary">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But the button (Filter) on the right side I want to disable it's alignment and place it on a new row, on the left side, under the other input fields. How do I manage that?

(Because it's rendered by Drupal, it's difficult to get the button out of the flex wrapper `bulk-filter-wrapper d-flex`).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can put the button inside a full width div, and add `flex-wrap` to the `d-flex` container.

```
<div class="w-100">
    <input type="submit" id="edit-submit-content" value="Filter" class="button js-form-submit form-submit btn btn-primary">
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/WSrEPAvTQ1

Comment: If I click above button, another button appears. But this 'Reset' button is appearing under the other button (because of the `w-100 class`. How do I align them both horizontally (but both together in one row)?